# Quick Sort implementation in python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, sorting

I am trying to write a quick sort in place function
here is my code

```
def quick_sort(ar):
    if len(ar) < 2:
        return ar
    pivot = ar[-1]
    i = 0

    for j in range(len(ar)):
        if ar[j] < pivot:
            ar[i], ar[j] = ar[j] , ar[i]
            i += 1
    ar[i], ar[-1] = ar[-1], ar[i]

    quick_sort(ar[0:i])
    quick_sort(ar[i+1:])

    return ar


lst = [1, 3, 9, 8, 2, 7, 5]
print quick_sort(lst)
```

but i get an empty list in return.. what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an empty list? When I test the code you've shown, I get a list with all the expected numbers in it, just not in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive calls are being made on slices of your list. Slicing makes a copy, so the recursion does not change the original list at all. You either need to use the return values from the recursive calls, or you should do everything in-place. Each of those requires a few changes to your code, just in different places

Here's a version of your code that builds a new list:

```
def quick_sort(ar):
    if len(ar) < 2:
        return ar
    pivot = ar[-1]
    i = 0

    for j in range(len(ar)):
        if ar[j] < pivot:
            ar[i], ar[j] = ar[j] , ar[i]
            i += 1
    ar[i], ar[-1] = ar[-1], ar[i]

    result = quick_sort(ar[0:i]) # build a new result list from the recursive calls
    result.append(pivot)
    result.extend(quick_sort(ar[i+1:]))

    return result
```

And here's one that sorts in-place:

```
def quick_sort(ar, low=0, high=None):   # get sorting bounds as arguments
    if high is None:
        high = len(ar)
    if high - low < 2:
        return
    pivot = ar[high-1]
    i = low

    for j in range(low, high):   # iterate on a limited range
        if ar[j] < pivot:
            ar[i], ar[j] = ar[j] , ar[i]
            i += 1
    ar[i], ar[high-1] = ar[high-1], ar[i]

    quick_sort(ar, low, i)
    quick_sort(ar, i+1, high)

    # no need to return anything, since we sorted ar in place
```

Given how you're doing the partitioning, the in-place version probably makes more sense. The other version would be more interesting if paired with a partitioning scheme that made it a stable sort (there's no easy way to do a stable quicksort in-place).